# I cannot delete duplicated development provisioning profiles of the same appID

Tags: ios, xcode, duplicates, profile, provisioning

Using Xcode 5.1 (Xcode -> Preferences -> Account -> View Detail) and pressing the refresh button
I get the list of my provisioning profile.
The problem is that I have duplicate provisioning profile of the same AppID.
I tried to eliminate using different solutions read on internet without any results.
Every time I try to get list of the provisioning profile I get the same list with duplicates.

In detail I tried:
1) iphone configuration utilities (i delete all my profile using this program without success)

2) I removed the directory where provisioning profile are saved /User/$(username)/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/ AND relative DB without success

3) I tried to delete profile from develper account without success

4) I remove all profile/certificate from my device and I remove these device from dev account. Once I removed my devices i try again step 1) 2) and 3) without success.

5) I have also "clean" my keychain without success.

Any suggestion? I have already spent 2 days and I have to publish the new version of my app
thanks

Comment: @VinayBagale Yes in step 2)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need delete duplicated provisioning profiles from developer portal. Then you could remove it locally on you machine.
Also it shouldn't be reason for failing app publication. For example you can have several provisioning profiles for one bundle id if you create one for distribution and one for development. But in project settings you should select one that you need:
 [image: target settings]

If you have several provisioning profiles with the same name, certificate and bundle id then it looks like a bug. In this case try to uninstall xcode, and install it from scratch.